# Trying to Add date condition filter in DataView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add date condition filter in data recieved but getting error "The expression contains undefined function call DateTime.Today.AddDays()."
How to resolve any idea would be appreciated.
Below are the details

```
Public Class FileFilter
 Public FileId As Integer
        Public ParentFileId As Integer
        Public InternalVersion As Double
        Public SectionId As Integer
        Public FieldId As Integer
        Public TemplateID As Integer
Public DateValue As Date
End Class

Public Sub poladd()
 Dim objFileFilter As ICMSBAL.FileFilter = Nothing
 Dim dvPolicyDetails As DataView = Nothing
 Dim dtPolicyDetails As DataTable = Nothing
dvPolicyDetails = dtPolicyDetails.AsDataView()
dvPolicyDetails.RowFilter = "SectionId=" & FieldMaps.fileSectionInstalment & " and FieldId='464' and DateFlag='Y' and FileID=" & objPolicy.PolFileID & " and DateValue>=DateTime.Today  And DateValue<= DateTime.Today.AddDays(60)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use string concatenation (which you shouldn't):

```vb
dvPolicyDetails.RowFilter = "SectionId = " & FieldMaps.fileSectionInstalment & " AND FieldId = '464' AND DateFlag = 'Y' AND FileID = " & objPolicy.PolFileID & " AND DateValue >= #" & Date.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") & "# AND DateValue <= #" & Date.Now.AddDays(60).ToString("M/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

That assumes that `SectionId` and `FileID` are numeric while `FieldId` is text, which is what your original code implies.

A better option would be to use `String.Format`:

```vb
dvPolicyDetails.RowFilter = String.Format("SectionId = {0} AND FieldId = '464' AND DateFlag = 'Y' AND FileID = {1} AND DateValue >= #{2:M/dd/yyyy}# AND DateValue <= #{3:M/dd/yyyy}#",
                                          FieldMaps.fileSectionInstalment,
                                          objPolicy.PolFileID,
                                          Date.Now,
                                          Date.Now.AddDays(60))
```

Nowadays, it would be best practice to use string interpolation:

```vb
dvPolicyDetails.RowFilter = $"SectionId = {FieldMaps.fileSectionInstalment} AND FieldId = '464' AND DateFlag = 'Y' AND FileID = {objPolicy.PolFileID} AND DateValue >= #{Date.Now:M/dd/yyyy}# AND DateValue <= #{Date.Now.AddDays(60):M/dd/yyyy}#"
```